# UIImage not working properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, asynchronous

i m trying load UIImages from server asynchronously in UITableViewCell.
My code worked fine in simulator but not on device. My code as follows,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 IScopeCustomTableCell *cell = (IScopeCustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellClassName];

if (!cell){
    NSArray *topLevelItems = [cellLoader instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.delegate = self;
cell.videoTitle.text = [[videoDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"VideoTitle"];
cell.videoLink = [[videoDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"VideoLink"];
cell.videoThumbnailImageLink = [[videoDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"VideoThumbnail"];
cell.videoThumbnail.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self
                                    selector:@selector(loadImage:)
                                    object:cell];
[queue addOperation:operation];
return cell;
}

- (void)loadImage:(IScopeCustomTableCell *)cell {
NSLog(@"Image link :- %@", cell.videoThumbnailImageLink);

//NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cell.videoThumbnailImageLink]];
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cell.videoThumbnailImageLink]];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

cell.videoThumbnail.image = image;
[cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[cell.activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

//[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

The above code fine on simulator but not on device, becoz, UIImage *image get (0X0)null in  even though NSData loadImage method containing appropriate data.

Comment: howmany mb of the file size come from the server ???

Comment: Sorry for stating the obvious, but you already checked that your device has access to the web, don't you ? Also, firing a thread each time the cell is displayed is not the best solution. You can find many tutorial on the web for loading image asynchronously.

Comment: @Leonardo, please give me link if u have loading image asynchronously...

Comment: You can refer this Apple sample code : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394

Comment: this one is also quite nice: http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Comment: @Leonardo, thanks, Actually my code worked good, its my bad intentions that my company device has not access of that given link so that it not working properly on device... i got binary data but that binary data was access denied message from server... that why UIImage not recognized binary information and i get null memory.... nw i code worked fine. Thanks again to given ur valuable time for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link containing image cache code and it worked properly exact that i would like.

https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache

Comment: http://maniacdev.com/2012/04/best-resources-in-ios-development-april-2nd-2012/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+maniacdev+%28iPhone%2C+iOS+4%2C+iPad+SDK+Development+Tutorial+and+Programming+Tips%29

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not the best way to do it as it will create many autoreleased objects and will increase the size of your app and also you are not releasing your `operation`... so first of all release your `operation` after `[queue addOperation:operation];`

and use this code instead for getting the image data and storing it in your image...

```
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cell.videoThumbnailImageLink]]];
UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
[data release];
cell.videoThumbnail.image = image;
[img release];
```

hoping this sorts your problem..